# CEFsharp & Cefglue (chromium embedded) media player plugins not working in WPF controls. (NPAPI)

Tags: wpf, vlc, npapi, browser-plugin, chromium-embedded

I'm using javascript to replace html5 video tag's with references to VLC or Windows Media Player browser plugins in order to be able to play h.264 video's in a chromium embedded WPF control.

For example:

```
<object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" width="300px" height="150px" spellcheck="true"      uimode="full"><param name="autostart" value="true"><param name="url"   value="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"></object>
```

This technique works in cefclient.exe and in CEFsharp and Cefglue Winforms controls. However when doing this in either CEFsharp WPF control or Cefglue WPF control, the screen just stays blank and the console shows no errors. Even debugging on level verbose shows no errors. I've tried referencing the paths to the plugins:

CefRuntime.AddWebPluginPath(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\npvlc.dll");
CefRuntime.AddWebPluginDirectory(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC");

But the players (VLC and WMP) still don't show.

I got a feeling that WPF is somehow not allowed to access the plugins.

I really hope you can help me with this one, because using Winforms is not an option for me as I need to be able to perform a rotatetransform on the control.

**UPDATE:**
 Just realised that this probably has something to do with CEF3 offscreen rendering. Is it possible to disable OSR in CEF3, and will this impact performance much?

Comment: What did you end up doing?